# Installing Ubuntu on PowerBook G4

Tags: mac, macosx

I have a Mac PowerBook G4.

It has the Mac OS X Version 10.5.8 on it.

I would love to change it to Ubuntu but the last time I tried it wouldn't register the disc.

Any ideas if I need an older version or what needs to be installed in a certain way?

Comment: Here's a good place to start on the installation: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPC

Comment: a start would be http://powerpcliberation.blogspot.de/2012/10/lubuntu-install-guide.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "wouldn't register the disc" but to boot an older iBook / PowerBook from the optical drive, just hold down the C button as soon as you power on.

Another option is to boot into OpenFirmware.  This can be done by holding down Cmd-Option-O-F as you power on.  Once OpenFirmware has started (a white screen with a short message and a simpole prompt) enter the command: boot cd

I hope this helps.  I'm going from memory.

Edit for Addition:

Also, just a warning: Years ago when I used Linux on a MacBook there was no Linux driver available for the Broadcom wifi chipset that Apple used in their laptops. At the time, the only option was to use a usb attached wifi device. This may no longer be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

A start would be this tutorial for Lubuntu 12.04 http://powerpcliberation.blogspot.de/2012/10/lubuntu-install-guide.html.

Lubuntu is optimized for old computers.

the latest Images you find here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/ (currently 13.04)
use the "Mac (PowerPC) and IBM-PPC (POWER5) desktop image" in http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.04/release/

I tried it on a PowerMac G4 and it seems to work. (although, while it's trying to install, I get the message

> !! Select and install software
>   Installation step failed.
>   An installation step failed. You can try to run the following item again from the menu, or skip it and choose something else. The failing step is: Load installer components from CD.

But that seems to be due to an error on the old harddrive I inserted into the G4, I see some I/O errors in syslog when I change to the console with Ctrl+Alt+F1 )

Comment: I asked about this bug in the apple stack here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98190/install-linux-on-a-g4-select-and-install-software-installation-step-failed